# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=11; regionStart=0; regionLength=2560

Tags: java

i can't get rid of this error. i have serached a lot but not related to my code(problem)

```
 if (recorder.getState() == AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED){
                    Log.d("VS", "Recorder working....c");
                    recorder.startRecording();}

                BufferedWriter input;
                while(status == true) {


                    minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    (buffer,buffer.length,destination,port);





                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
                    out.write(buffer.toString(), 0, buffer.length);



                    out.flush();
```

thnaks in advance...!

Comment: Can you put the stacktrace of the exception and mark the line on which the exception is being thrown?

Comment: it dose compile. problem is this line                     out.write(buffer.toString(), 0, buffer.length);

Comment: It definitely will not compile, fix the code if my answer didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of this exception is pretty obvious, string length is only 11 and buffer length is 2560.

```
out.write(buffer.toString(), 0, buffer.toString().length());
```

Should work, it uses string length instead of buffer length.
But if that is what you wanted you could just use

```
out.write(buffer.toString());
```

Comment: great answer.!! works very well. will you help me with whole code??error fixed but its not sending the data to server.

Comment: I guess that you need to make new question if you need help in another issue, I don't have experience about sending data to server with java. Are you sure that it's not sent to your server? Maybe your server does not work correctly. Consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: how can i accept it? i do not have enough reptaioun to vote you up.sorry